# Arrow up/down at the selected column

Tags: html, ionic-framework

**I want the sorting column show the arrow up or down if it is selected only as below.**
Example:

when sort age from ascending, only arrow up at age and no arrow up or down at the other two

[image]

when sort name from descending. and there is again no arrow up/down at the other two column

[image]

In my code with ionic 1 framework, it will show both arrow up and down, no matter how I sort

**html**

```
<div class="col col-33" ng-click="reverse = (orderWith=='Name')? !reverse: reverse;orderWith='Name'">Name<i class="material-icons">&#xE316;</i>?<i class="material-icons">&#xE313;</i></div>
<div class="col" ng-click="reverse = (orderWith=='Trade')? !reverse: reverse;orderWith='Trade'">Call<i class="material-icons">&#xE316;</i>?<i class="material-icons">&#xE313;</i></div>
<div class="col" ng-click="reverse = (orderWith=='num')? !reverse: reverse;orderWith='num'">Number<i class="material-icons">&#xE316;</i>?<i class="material-icons">&#xE313;</i></div>
```

[image]

As you can see, both arrow up and down is shown together. Also, the arrow is suppose shown for the selected column only but it shows for all columns.
How to have the correct arrow up/down at the column I selected only?

Comment: Would this do it? https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui/grids-and-lists (jquery datatable). Its what I use, and it works perfect.

Comment: @RonnieOosting, not seems to be suitable or what I am needed. I need the html code.

Comment: As far as I know this needs to be done through javascript. this? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp